# Angular app slow initialization with ui-grid and larger data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

The aim of my app is to load larger amounts of data, through html parameter directive data binding, and to subsequently show this data in Angular ui-grid.

The problem with this is very slow initialization which tends to get slower as my data gets bigger.

I have tried numerous solutions but nothing seems to increase my init time. The code looks like this

```
(function (root, factory) { //To make an app ready for dependency injection
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        // CommonJS
        module.exports = factory(require('angular'));
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['angular'], factory);
    } else {
        // Global Variables
        factory(root.angular);
    }
}(this, function (angular) {

    'use strict';
     var app = angular.module('rpTabelaSerije', ['ngRoute', 'ngDialog', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit',
        'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.autoResize'
    ]);

    return app;
}))
```

and then the main directive

```
app.directive('rpTabelaSerije', function (ngDialog, $rootScope, $timeout, $http, $templateCache, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            rb:"=",
            x:"=rpx",
            y:"=rpy",
            id:"=rpid",
            enabled: '=rpenabled',
            edit: '=rpedit',
            dodavanje: '=rpdodavanje',
            brisanje: '=rpbrisanje',
        },
        template: '<div id="tabela" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-infinite-scroll ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-edit ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-auto-resize class="uk-container-center tabelarniPrikaz uk-margin-large-top"></div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element,uiGridConstants) {
                $scope.serije = [];
                $scope.gridOptions = {
                enableColumnMenus: false,
                enableSorting: false,
                enableGridMenu: true,
                enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
                enableSelectAll: true,
                multiSelect: true,
                modifierKeysToMultiSelectCells: true,
                enableFiltering: false,
                flatEntityAccess: true,             
                        columnDefs: [{
                            name: 'id',
                            displayName: '#',
                            type: 'number',
                            width: 30,
                            enableCellEdit: false
                                            }, {
                            name: 'x',
                            displayName: 'Datum',
                            type: 'date',
                            width: 137,
                            enableCellEdit: false
                                            }, {
                            name: 'y',
                            displayName: 'Vrednost',
                            type: 'number',
                            width: 80,
                            enableCellEdit: true
                        }]  
            }; 
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.serije = scope.$eval(attrs['rpserije']); //Here is like this because I taught that one-way binding will solve the problem (but its the same as if I pass it as a scope inherited parameter) 
                    console.log(scope.serije);
                    scope.gridOptions.data = scope.serije[0].podaciSerije;
        }

    };

});
```

which is intended for use like this

```
<rp-tabela-serije id="rptabela" rpenabled="true" rpedit="true" rpbrisanje="true" rpdodavanje="true" rpx="'x'" rpy="'y'" rpid="'id'" rpserije= // here any raw object can be inserted from other scopes, etc //><rp-tabela-serije>
```

with sample data like this

```
[
    {
        "id"  : 1,
        "y"  : 19.15,
        "x"  : "2014-03-02 00:03:00"
    }
]
```

With 3500 data points this setup tends to initialize for 8-10 sec before the content is shown (and I need it for 20000+ data), where for i.e. 10000 it hangs indefinitely.

One thing that worked out ok (the app shows on page instantly) was the usage of $http.get in order to load the data from the server json file (like in the ui-grid tutorial [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/190_large_dataset)). But unfortunately I can't have external files here, so they must be passed through scope inheritance or directly from the html tag parameters.

I have also tried pre-loading the template in $templateCache, and using preLink and postLink functions during compile time, but every-time it's the same.
Any ideas?

Comment: is a 'load more' button an option? Start with rendering 100 records and then on a button click, or after the prev 100 have been loaded, load the next batch. It'll take even longer than loading everything at the same time, but at least your program won't become unresponsive on startup.

Comment: Definitely worth a look, but there are some problems with this approach. The users expect to pass the entire data through html-tag parameter and I have no idea how I could load from there part by part. Whether I put it as an isolate scope data binding or do it through scope.eval it still takes up the whole data prior to any function I can invoke, or am I wrong?